# Add fields dynamically with formbuilder

Tags: angular, forms, angular2-formbuilder

[image]Im building one quiz application.Number of Answer options will be dynamic.

```
 this.quizForm=this.fb.group({
  slNo:[1,[Validators.required]],
  qn:['',Validators.required],
  ans:['',Validators.required],
  pickedAns:[''],
  options:[],    ==>options have id,answertext fields
  total:[0,[Validators.required]],
  correct:[0,[Validators.required]],
  wrong:[0,[Validators.required]],
  left:[0,[Validators.required]],  })
```

How to add options as dynamic and bind with ui?

Comment: [Dynamic forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form)

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar using a FormArray[].

In my ts:

// declare  array

```
answerOptions: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
```

// init

```
createForm() {
        this.quizForm = new FormGroup({
            answerOptions: this.formBuilder.array([])
        });
    }
```

//Add as required

```
addAnswerOptionControl(option: AnswerOption): void {
        this.answerOptions = this.quizForm.get('answerOptions') as FormArray;
        this.answerOptions.push(this.createOptionControl(option));
    }


createOptionControl(option: AnswerOption)): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
        option: new FormControl('', Validators...]
        )
    });
}

get formData() {
    return <FormArray>this.quizForm.get('answerOptions');
}
```

And in my view:

```
<div formArrayName="answerOptions" *ngFor="let option of formData.controls; let i = index">
                <div [formGroupName]="i">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            formControlName="answerOption"
                        />
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
            </div>
```